# Eventbrite API -- Attendees API returned 0 attendees

Tags: eventbrite

I was trying to retrieve the list of attendees for an event using the following endpoint, with the correct authorization token:

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/110736700452/attendees/

I verified from the web interface that the event does have attendees. However, the response return 0 attendees:

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "object_count": 0,
        "page_number": 1,
        "page_size": 50,
        "page_count": 1,
        "has_more_items": false
    },
    "attendees": []
}
```

I have tried using another eventbrite account, create an event, and call the API (using the corresponding authorization token), and I get the attendees list back.

Any idea what I was missing why the first one would have no attendees returned, when the event at like 50 attendees?

Comment: If this is a problem with just one event then you should probably ask Eventbrite's support about it directly.

Comment: Agree, except I couldn't find any support contacts. Do you happen to have one you can share?

Comment: No, sorry, I’ve never used their API. It looks like there’s a few helpful employees on their Google group but no guaranteed support unless you have a professional or premium Eventbrite package.

Comment: Go to know about the Google Group support. Will try there. Thanks, Rup!